# Do JobIntentServices limits the number of threads? Application with multiple JobIntentServices is gives just two threads for all services

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, intentservice, jobintentservice

I was expecting that multiple JobIntentServices would use always one thread for each.

I have several JobIntentServices

```
class Client1 : JobIntentService() {
...
}
```

,

```
class Client2 : JobIntentService() {
...
}
```

,

```
class Client3 : JobIntentService() {
...
}
```

,

```
class Client4 : JobIntentService() {
...
}
```

and so on. And one Intent for each ex:

```
val client1Intent = Intent(this, Client1::class.java)

client1Intent.putExtra("some_name", info) 
client1Intent.putExtra("other_name", otherInfo) Client1.enqueueWork(this, client1Intent)
```

When I check the thread on `override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent)`

```
override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
...
Log.d(TAG, "Current THREAD: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
}
```

I see in logcat that the services were separated in just two threads:

**Thread[AsyncTask #2,5,main]** and **Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main]**

Therefore they are running just two each time. I expected that the number of asynctasks would be equals to the number of JobIntentServices. Why it is not so?

Comment: During your testing did you enqueue enough work to keep more than 2 threads busy at the same time?

Comment: The work is to make calls with OkHTTP. Each JobIntentService has one client created with OkHttpClient.Builder().build() . The OkHttp requests take some time to be answered by the server. Could OkHTTP be influencing the number of threads created?